# MainWindow.xib Adding ViewControllers

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am using Xcode 3.2.  How can I add more ViewControllers when I make them via "new file" to the MainWindow panel in the Interface Builder.  For example, in this picture the bottom 2 squares are there by default.  How do I add similar ones to represent the new ViewController(s) I just added.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 1 view controller per nib. Create a different nib for that and any other view controllers you want, or start using storyboards (which requires you to update Xcode).

Comment: How do you create a new nib?  I only have options to create .xib

Comment: A nib and a xib are the same thing.